# How to display an XML file in a Laravel blade template?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-blade

I load an XML file and get the required element from it.
Like that:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.com');
$$exampleElement = $xml->shop->offers->offer;
```

If I output it via {{dd($exampleElement)}} in the blade template, I get this:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#478 ▼
  +"@attributes": array:3 [▶
    "id" => "835376"
    "available" => "false"
  ]
  +"categoryId": "2411"
   ...
  +"oldprice": "2690"
  +"param": array:7 [▶
    0 => SimpleXMLElement {#1642 ▶
      +"@attributes": array:1 [▶
        "name" => "Color"
      ]
      +"0": "Green"
    }
    1 => SimpleXMLElement {#1643 ▶
      +"@attributes": array:1 [▶
        "name" => "Brand"
      ]
      +"0": "Adidas"
    }
    ...
  ]
  +"picture": array:2 [▶
    0 => "https://example.com/1.jpg"
    1 => "https://example.com/2.jpg"
  ]
}
```

If I output in the standard way via {{$exampleElement}}, then nothing is displayed.

What do I need to do so that the output of the element is in this format?:

```
<categoryId>2411</categoryId>
<param name="Color">Green</param>
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SimpleXMLElement's `asXML` method:

> Return a well-formed XML string based on SimpleXML element

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

So in your case that would be: `{{ $exampleElement->asXML() }}`

If only want show the XML in your template and nothing else, and want the browser to handle output as XML, you should bypass the blade template / view and directly output the XML from your controller with the correct header:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.com');
$exampleElement = $xml->shop->offers->offer;
$exampleString = $exampleElement->asXML();

return response($exampleString, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you. This way (`{{ $exampleElement->asXML() }}`) works. But it outputs a line. Is it possible to somehow display it not as a line, but so that each element is on a new line and indented according to the hierarchy? *I added an image to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: `return response(...)` - That's how it works. But I need to somehow transfer this to the view.